# Excel - Match Values in 2 Columns

Tags: excel, excel-match

Consider the Columns `A` and `C`, where the values in `C` can be found in `A`.

How do I get a match where the following conditions are met?

- If a value of `C` is found in `A`, it will print a `1`.
- If no matches are found, it will print out `0` in column `B`.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything? Google? A book? A tutorial? An online course? An on-site course?

Comment: Have a look at VLOOKUP

Comment: `=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(C1,A:A,1,FALSE),0,1)`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

=IF(COUNTIF($J:$J,H152)=0,"0","1")